# Random shared between instances of an object?

Tags: java, random

I want to create a lot of instances of an object that uses a random number as part of its initialization, but if I make a massive number of these objects in a loop, most of them will be the same (I think). Can someone clarify? And if I'm correct in my assumption, is there a way to have them share a single Random object?

Comment: sharing the same random object wont help. theres a probability to get duplicate randoms even from the same object .

Comment: Depends on the range of your random number and the quality (period length) of your random number generator.

Comment: The question is a bit fuzzy, but: in general, code should use the *same* Random instance. The instance can be shared the same way any object is shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objects can share a single `java.util.Random` instance.  In fact, this will give you the best performance, versus creating a new instance of `Random` each time.

If you're dealing with multiple threads, even though `java.util.Random` is threadsafe, you should consider using `ThreadLocalRandom` introduced in JDK 1.7 instead, as it will significantly reduce thread contention.

For example:

```
public class ExampleClass {
    private static final Random random = new Random();

    public ExampleClass() {
        System.out.println("Constructor using random: " + random.nextInt(100));
    }

    public void methodThatUsesRandom() {
        System.out.println("Method using random: " + random.nextInt(100));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I asked for! And how might I achieve this?

Comment: There are several ways to go about this.  One way is to define a ``static final`` instance in your class, and then use it in a method.  See my post above for an example.